# What is the proper way to alter column parameters in AbpAuditLog?

Tags: asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

How can I alter column parameters in abpAuditLogs table?
I want to alter it to nvarchar(max)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can increase the size of AuditLog fields like this;

In DbContext class:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    AuditLog.MaxParametersLength = 4000;
    //other fields...

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    //...
}
```

> You can customize these fields;
>
> MaxServiceNameLength, MaxMethodNameLength, MaxParametersLength,
>   MaxClientIpAddressLength, MaxClientNameLength, MaxBrowserInfoLength,
>   MaxExceptionLength, MaxCustomDataLength

Comment: Wonderful. one of the best startup template.